# Is possible to check is list proper or improper in scheme?

Tags: list, scheme, lisp

I'm trying to create function which checks is list proper or improper. Can't find any solution in the internet. Is this possible?

For example we have code using `list?`:

```scm
(define (proper-list? list) 
  (cond
    ((list? list) '(it's a proper list)) 
    (else '(it's an improper list))))

(proper-list? '(a b c))
; -> (it's a proper list) - OK   
(proper-list? '(a b . c))
; -> (it's an improper list) - OK   
(proper-list? '(a . b))
; -> (it's an improper list)   
; - NOT OK. it should return (it's a pair)
```

How to distinguish improper list from pair?

Comment: Hey! Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're question is a little skimpy on the details. We can help you more efficiently if we have a good example to work from. Some tips at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `list?` does that. It iterates over every pair to check if the last `cdr` is `()` making it O(n). In the non Scheme language `#lang racket` I think `list?` is O(1)..

Comment: Does the function have to terminate even if the input list happens to be circular? Do you consider such a list proper or not?

Comment: @Sylwester, `list?` won't help. I've added more description of problem, please check it.

Comment: @Kaz, There is no need to work with circular list. Just linear.

Comment: the boolean result of `list?`decides if you need to return one or the other so `list?` is the correct answer. You cannot expect us to do your homework so the last bit with 4 lines of code that uses `list?` needs to be done by you.

Comment: @Sylwester,  I'm not asking you to do my homework. Why are you so rude and angry? You don't understand my question. For example we have code using `list?` as you said:  
`(define (proper-list? list)  
  (cond ((list? list) '(it's a proper list))
        (else '(it's an improper list))))`

`(proper-list? '(a b c))` -> `(it's a proper list)` - OK
`(proper-list? '(a b . c))` -> `(it's an improper list)` - OK
`(proper-list? '(a . b)) -> `(it's an improper list)` - NOT OK. it should return `(it's not a list)`
How to distinguish improper list from pair?

Comment: Sorry for formatting, it's my first question here.

Comment: Showing you code and asking more concrete questions will help getting better answers. You should do it by editing your question and add your code and specific (and related) question. `(a . b)` is a dotted list consisting of one pair with `'a` as its `car` and `'b` as its `cdr`. I have no idea why you would want that to return that it is not something that it clearly is.

Comment: @Sylwester, because my teacher want this :( Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `list?` checks wether a list is proper or not:

```
(list? '(1 2 3))   ; ==> #t
(list? '(1 2 . 3)) ; ==> #f
```

Use this in your function to return either of the two lists in your specification.

**EDIT**

Because of the strange requirement that `(a . b)` would not be considered a improper list I think you should add an extra term in you `cond` that differentiate the two improper lists of one pair in chain and more than one pair in chain by using `pair?` in the `cdr`. `(pair? (cdr '(a . b)) ; ==> #f` and `(pair? (cdr '(a b . c)) ; ==> #t`

Comment: `(list? '(1 . 2)) ; ==> #f`. I need to distinguish improper list from pair.

Comment: @MaxVishnevskyTotally crazy not to call `(cons 'a 'b)` a improper list but `(cons 'a (cons b 'c))` one, but I've added a hint.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've found solution with your help! :)

Comment: Every list that is not empty is a pair, whether a proper list or not.

Comment: @Kaz, I know it